# Does React component definetely update itself when a method is called

Tags: meteor, reactjs

Although you don t need to look at the code below to understand the question, I added it in case you need to visualize the scenario. Whenever the form submits, addList method is called.

And the component updates itself. But I didn t expect this behaviour, that s why at first I did try to assign my lists to state, so that when the state changed the component would update itself as I wanted.

Anyway it already updates itself, but why ? Which way is more efficient ?

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
import {Lists} from '../lib/collections/lists.js';

export default class App extends TrackerReact(Component) {
    constructor(){
        super();
        // this.state = {lists : this.lists()}
    }
    lists(){
        return Lists.find().fetch();
    }
    addList(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //let text = this.refs.list.value ;
        let text = this._inputList.value ;
        console.log(this._inputList.value);
        Lists.insert({
            title : text
        });
        this._inputList.value = "";

        //this.setState({lists : this.lists()});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Lists</h2>
                <ul>
                    {this.lists().map((a,b)=>(
                        <List key={a._id} title={a.title} /> 
                    ))} 
                </ul>
                <form onSubmit={this.addList.bind(this)}>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        ref={(input)=>{
                            this._inputList =  input ;
                        }}
                        placeholder="add list bro"
                    />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }  
}
```

Comment: because most likely your Lists that you are importing are getting updated and causing the top level component to re render. which then calls the get and re updates

Comment: What if I didn t have any data flow, I am just submitting and a method is called, would that cause rerendering of component without state being untouched?

Comment: Is the page reloading when you submit?

Comment: Well without looking into it (I'm on mobile) maybe it's because the class is extended from TrackerReact()

Comment: This might be true. Because I tested, componentWillUpdate doesnt log what want after method is called. But I am not sure if this is the correct way to test it.

Comment: Yea that's what it sounds like.. I'd look deeper into their implementation.. It's always good to know how your framework works :)

Comment: Definetely, but I have checked lifecycle methods of react and componentWillUpdate is not the method we are looking for. React doesn t have a lifecycle method to use to understand this problem. I guess we misunderstand what component rerendering means.

Comment: No you want shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: I have tried shouldComponentUpdate with the code in the question and the list I added is being updated to the screen but console.log() inside shouldComponentUpdate isn t being called.

Comment: But componentWillUpdate works as expected. I ll answer this question bu myself. the answer is method being called doesn t force component update itself unless state changes.

Comment: So another thing could be Lists.js not sure what that is but I see its in a collections folder so it might be something with that. aka when you insert a new item. I can't know without knowing the setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if we add a componentWillUpdate react life-cycle method to see if it rerenders ;

```
componentWillUpdate() {
 console.log('will update');     
}
```

When form submitted "will update" is logged on console as expected. However if we update addList as ;

```
addList(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // nothing else.
}
```

We don t see the output "will update" on console. Which means method being called doesn t require the component to be rerendered. There is no such a rule. In this case , it is probably about TrackerReact. TrackerReact might force the component to rerender.